# iterator passed by reference set/map iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference, iterator

I am having some trouble with passing an iterator by reference. In the program, I have three classes: the class A that contains a std::map> as a private member. The class B holding the class A as a private member. And the class C that receives in its constructor the class B. In the class C, I am trying to retrieve an iterator pointing to the map as follows:

```
class A(){
   private: 
        std::map<std::vector<>> theMap;
   public:
        void theMap_access() {std::string to_access , std::map<std::vector<>>::iterator &it){
        it =  theMap.find(to_access);
        it-> first; //OK
   }         
};

class B(){
   private: 
        A a;
   public: 
        A A_access(){return a;}
};

class C(B &b){
   public: 
       std::map<std::vector<>>::iterator it;
       std::string to_access = "test";
       B.A_access().theMap_access(to_access, it);
       it-> first; //KO
};
```

When I execute this code, I am sure "test" is in the map. So when I dereference it in class A, the code runs fine and I get it->first = "test". But after passing it by reference back to class C, I get this error: set/map iterator not dereferencable. I assume the iterator once passed back is not pointing to what it was pointing to in class A. Could you please explain me why and how I can fix that? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: std::map<std::vector<>> theMap . It cant be compiled map takes two template arguments.

Comment: `B.A_access()` in your usage in class `C` returns a copy of the `A` object, and that copy goes away before `it->first` is executed.

Comment: But even when I amend the code to return an iterator like that: (in class C) it = B.A_access().theMap_access(to_access);  and (in class A) std::map<std::vector<>>::iterator theMap_access() {std::string to_access){  it =  theMap.find(to_access); return it;} I am facing the same issue. Do you know how I could fix that and point to theMap from class C. Thank you.

Comment: @Eglantine No, it has nothing to do with the setting of the iterator.  It has everything to do with what `A_access` returns.  You are erroneously working with copies of `A`, and those copies disappear after that line is executed.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is fixed! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get this error: set/map iterator not dereferencable.

That is because the `A` object that is being used here in the return of `B.A_access`:

`B.A_access().theMap_access(to_access, it);`

no longer exists after the above line is executed.  So the iterator you set is referring to a non-existing `map`, since that `map` also has gone away.

The reason why is that `B.A_access()` returns a *copy* of the `A` object, and not the actual `A` object that contains the `std::map` you're trying to use.

If you want to use the actual `A` object that contains the `std::map` you want to manipulate, then `A_access` should return a reference to `A`, not a copy of `A`.

So the fix should be:

```
 A& A_access(){return a;}
```